# C# windows service can't stop

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm getting "The service cannot accept control messages at this time" when trying to stop the service. I don't really understand why this is happening. Can someone help me with this? I thought my lock would prevent this.

The Patrol method takes about ~30-40 sec to run.

```
private static readonly string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
private static readonly int runMinInterval = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RunMinInterval"]);
private Object myLock = new Object();
private Timer timer;

public DealWatchdogService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Watchdog.Patrol(ConnectionString, new DealWatchdogService());
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Interval = 60000 * runMinInterval;
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Start();
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    lock (myLock)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer = null;
        base.OnStop();
    }
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (myLock)
    {
         if (timer == null)
                return;
         Watchdog.Patrol(tycheConnection, new DealWatchdogService());
         timer.Start();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Maybe some help but the service stops fine sometimes, but when it has been up and running for a week or so I get that error.

Comment: If that's `System.Timers.Timer`, you shouldn't use both [`Enabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Start`: "Setting Enabled to true is the same as calling Start" (and you probably shouldn't enable it before you've configured the desired interval). Probably not your current issue but worth bearing in mind.

Comment: Yes it's System.Timers.Timer. I will have a look on that and change of course.

Comment: Do you use `myLock` anywhere other than OnStop()? if not the lock is not providing any benefit, only one thread at a time will ever call OnStop()

Comment: Its also used inside timer_Elapsed. Have updated with more code

Answer (score 1):

> The Patrol method takes about ~30-40 sec to run.

I think the problem may be OnStart() is taking too long because of Patrol's length to finish and is setting a flag stating the system is locked up. Put your startup code on to a background thread so OnStart can finish more quickly.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    //This line does not block.
    Task.Run(() => RealStart());
}

private void RealStart()
{
    Watchdog.Patrol(ConnectionString, new DealWatchdogService());
    timer = new Timer();
    //timer.Enabled = true; //Calling .Start() has the same effect.
    timer.Interval = 60000 * runMinInterval;
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start(); //Start should be called after you have set .Elapsed
}
```

The only other thing it could be is something is going wrong inside `timer_Elapsed` but you never showed us what that code is doing.

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong but isn't OnStart called only when service is started? The service starts fine. But is OnStart() blocking anyway?

Comment: @krillezzz it is, but I have seen services get in to a odd state when stuff goes wrong inside OnStart().